# sed: remove between delimeters IF a string is present between them

Tags: sed

Right now I have a multiline string matching this format:

```
---
some text
more text
MATCH: FIRST
more text
---
some text
more text
---
some text
MATCH: SECOND
more text
---
some
more
MATCH: THIRD
text
here
---
```

I'm looking for a way in bash (preferably using sed) to remove everything between `---` and `---` if `MATCH: FIRST` or `MATCH: SECOND` are present between them. i.e. for the above example I would want my output to look like:

```
---
some text
more text
---
some
more
MATCH: THIRD
text
here
---
```

For my purposes I don't really care either way if the delimiters are removed (the `---`). Any help is appreciated.

The closest I've gotten is doing something along these lines:

```
sed -e "/---*[MATCH: ]FIRST\|SECOND[^---]/,/---/d"
```

but I seem to be missing something.

Comment: `preferably using sed` In sed - it will be extremely and unnecessarily hard to do it. I strongly recommend pick another tool, like awk, perl or python. If you _really_ want to use `sed`, read a decent sed introduction. Become familiar with hold and pattern space and how to work with them and how `sed` language works.

Answer (score 0):

The `---` are easily repeatable and easily to "catch". Accumulate blocks separated by `---` into hold space, then match the whole hold space with the searched pattern. If it does not match, print it.

The following shell script:

```
cat <<EOF |
---
some text
more text
MATCH: FIRST
more text
---
some text
more text
---
some text
MATCH: SECOND
more text
---
some
more
MATCH: THIRD
text
here
---
moretest
---
andnaotherone
---
MATCH: SECOND
---
MATCH: SECOND
---
EOF
sed -n '
/^---$/!{H;b} # Accumulate one block
H;x;
# If there is the searched pattern
/\nMATCH: \(FIRST\|SECOND\)\n/!{
    s/^\n// # the leading newline from H
    p
} ; : OKEY
# Clear hold space so its empty
s/.*//;h
b
'
```

outputs:

```
---                                                                                                                                     
some text
more text
---
some
more
MATCH: THIRD
text
here
---
moretest
---
andnaotherone
---
```